# SQL Server table add id of last visits in GROUP query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a SQL Server database table with the list of users and their last visit. I would like to extract a list of the last visit for all visitors, together with the table id.

Let me explain better by giving an example.
Here's a simplified version

```
Visits
| id | visitor | last_visit |
|----|---------|------------|
|   1|     ABC | 2014-04-06 |
|   2|     DEF | 2014-04-06 |
|   3|     GHI | 2014-04-07 |
|   4|     DEF | 2014-04-07 |
|   5|     ABC | 2014-04-08 |
|   6|     JKL | 2014-04-10 |
|   7|     DEF | 2014-04-12 |
```

And here's what I would like to obtain:

```
| id | visitor | last_visit |
|----|---------|------------|
|   3|     GHI | 2014-04-07 |
|   5|     ABC | 2014-04-08 |
|   6|     JKL | 2014-04-10 |
|   7|     DEF | 2014-04-12 |
```

I managed to get the result WITHOUT the id column by doing a simple GROUP:

```
SELECT visitor, MAX(last_visit) FROM visits GROUP BY visitor
```

But I don't have a clue on how to add the id, which is fundamental for my purpose.

Comment: If you have **full certainty** that last_vist is incremental alongside increment of ID, you could just take `max(ID)`. It **looks** the case for the example, so.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.visitor, a.last_visit
FROM visits a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT visitor, MAX(last_visit) last_visit 
            FROM visits 
            GROUP BY visitor
          ) AS b on a.visitor = b .visitor and a.last_visit = b.last_visit;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT a.id, a.visitor, a.last_visit 
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.visitor ORDER BY a.last_visit DESC) AS RowNo, 
             a.id, a.visitor, a.last_visit
      FROM visits a
    ) AS a 
WHERE RowNo = 1;
```

Comment: I have a large number of records, which of the two will give better performance?

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number()` instead of `group by`:

```
select v.*
from (select v.*, row_number() over (partition by visitor order by last_visit desc) as seqnum
      from visits v
     ) v
where seqnum = 1;
```